# regex find and replace file path

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to find and replace a file path. The first part through "...uploads/" is consistent and need to be replaced. The year and month folder change and in the end need to go away. Then the image name.

For example this:
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/images-7.jpeg

Becomes this:
http://info.newsite.com/images/house/images-7.jpeg

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you trying to do the replace (server, client)?

Comment: I'm doing a data migration from Wordpress to Drupal and the image paths are not updating. I don't know regex at all so my previous attempts were shots in the dark that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/\d+/\d+/
```

with

```
http://info.newsite.com/images/house/
```

The `\d+` will match the varying year and month values.